# gcc 4.9.3: more aggressive NULL pointer check removal

Tags: gcc, g++, gcc4.9, g++4.9

I have the following code excerpt (extract from a big project), when compiled using `gcc 4.9.3` with `-O2` or `-O3`, it crashes when it tries to dereference `s` inside the `if` block (`s->someField`) because `s` is a `NULL` pointer.

By disassembling this code in gdb, I noticed that the null check is actually optimized out by the compiler, which explains the crash. I googled a bit and found there is an option `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` supposed to solve this problem, but it behaves the same after I compiled the code with this option.

```
void someFunc(struct MyStruct *s)
{
    if (s != NULL)
    {
       cout << s->someField << endl;
       delete s;
    }
 }
```

This doesn't break in `gcc 4.7.2`.

Another data point is, if I change the code to the following, it works perfectly fine in `gcc 4.9.3`. In gdb, it looks like the `NULL` check is **not** optimized out in this case.

```
void someFunc(struct MyStruct *s)
{
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    cout << s->someField << endl;
    delete s;
}
```

Although I know that I can change the code to make it work, but it is a big project and there is no way for me to change similar cases everywhere, is there some other compiler flags to switch off the compiler optimization for null check?

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing I'd consider a bug. I just tested it in 5.3.0 and it does not misbehave. Is upgrading an option? If not, you might want to address it with the developers.

Comment: No, upgrade is not an option for me

Comment: By any chance, have you cast this struct to some other pointer type outside this function? I'm wondering if this could be some form of strict aliasing issue. It's really the best idea I have beyond "compiler bug". Perhaps try `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: Is this related to the bug we reported here, we always see crashes when using wxWidgets library building with GCC's O2 option, see: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71867

Comment: Please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the code you provide is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any resolution on this?